# password_verify failing for password created on another server

Tags: php, bcrypt, password-hash, php-password-hash

I am running into a situation where I have two servers that sit behind a load balancer. I used password_hash() to generate a password on one server.

Something basically like this

```
password_hash('XXXXXXXXX', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Within my application when I make a request to an endpoint that uses password_verify() when the request goes to server 1 the password is properly verified and the request is validated, however when the load balancer sends the request to server 2 password_verify() appears to be unable to verify the password.

I have verified that both servers are using the exact same version of PHP, compiled on the same day running PHP 7.1.2. Is there something else I am missing here?

Comment: _sidenote:_ "unable to decrypt the password"_ - password_verify does _not_ decrypt the password. It hashes the same way as password_hash (with hopefully the same salt - which might be your problem) and does a timesave comparison.

Comment: @Jeff understood, password_verify returns false on server 2 but returns true on server 1

Comment: Stupid question: Are the two web servers using the same database?

Comment: @kungphu yes, both servers are reading from the same database

Comment: Have you _verified_ that your input data for the function is the exact same in both cases?

Comment: @Jeff do different servers generate different salts? If so can I get around this issue by providing my own salt to the password_hash method?

Comment: @Xenology To be honest, I don't know. Normally the salt would be stored with the hash. I can't answer/solve your problem, sorry!

Comment: The salt isn't the issue as it is stored with the hash. Hashes generated through `password_hash()` are server independent. Everything needed to verifying a hash is in the hash itself. The only difference I could thing of that could possibly be an issue is if the server where the hash was created on were compiled with `Argon2i` support (which then was used) while the other server wasn't. If that's not the case, then there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

After reading about `password_hash` in more detail from

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

`string password_hash ( string $password , int $algo [, array $options ] )`

I found that the use of `password_hash('XXXXXXXXX', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

won't work for load balancing, at least not without heavily modding the function or rolling your own version of it.

`PASSWORD_DEFAULT` outputs a hashed password specific to that instance, doesn't really go into much detail about it other than that the salt option is depreciated in php7+

More options for `$algo` (like Argon2i) were not added until php7.2, so you'll need to upgrade from php7.1 as your only option at the moment is using bycrypt with cost being the only option.

http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php

Either way this goes, it's been an ongoing issue even for load balancing oauth servers. Where the generated token on server 1 won't work for server 2. 
  One workaround to this has been to use a shared cache and database, which defeats the purpose of load balancing to separate hardware, and even different networks. 
  The other option is using a sticky feature on the load balancer.

One thing to definitely avoid is using the same salts for your hash to work around this issue. Working with the following steps for hashing should work across all your servers if you use the same database.

Generate a long random salt using a CSPRNG or any other method of generating random salts. An interesting side note, hardware/physical random number generators such as the Lavarand.
Prepend the salt to the password and hash it with a standard password hashing function like Argon2i.
Save both the salt and the hash in the user's database record.

Retrieve the user's salt and hash from the database.
Prepend the salt to the given password and hash it using the same hash function.
Compare the hash of the given password with the hash from the database. If they match, the password is correct. Otherwise, the password is incorrect.

for example ---

```
<?php

$salt = random_bytes(100);

$password = 'password';

$combined = '$password' + $salt;


$hash = password_hash('$combined', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify('$combined', $hash)) {

    echo 'true';
} else { 
    echo 'no go';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the two servers do not support the same algorithms, server1 probably calculates an Argon2 hash while server2 does not know about this algorithm yet.

You can fix the algorithm for the moment, this should solve your problem until both servers understand both algorithms, then you should switch back to `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`.

```
password_hash('XXXXXXXXX', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```